# Run a Cli command from an Electron packaged app

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, child-process

I'm writing a Mac OSX GUI with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) and [Nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier) package and when i run the packaged app on a machine with Nodejs installed (globally), everything works fine.
On a machine without Nodejs installed the command can't be found.

I'm using the Nativefier Cli inside Electron with a full path to cli:

```
var cliCmd = '"'+app.getAppPath()+'/node_modules/nativefier/lib/cli.js"';

const child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec(cliCmd+' --name "App Name" "http://appname.tld" --platform darwin --arch x64 --electron-version "0.36.6"', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

I'm getting this error: `"env: node: No such file or directory"`
Checked the `app.getAppPath()` dir and it's correct.

Also, i tried to pass the `env` and `cwd` parameters, but without any success.

```
child_process.exec(cliCmd+' --name "App Name" "http://appname.tld" --platform darwin --arch x64 --electron-version "0.36.6"',
{
  env: {"ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE":"1"},
  cwd: app.getAppPath()
},
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

What i'm doing wrong? I tried `child_process.spawn()` also, but without any luck again.
What i need to do to call a packaged node_module/cli from my app, on a machine without nodejs installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found `execPath` inside the `process` object
and now i can execute nodejs commands on a machine without nodejs installed globally. It's using the Electron's built-in version.

```
child_process.exec(process.execPath+' '+cliCmd+' --name "App Name" "http://appname.tld" --platform darwin --arch x64 --electron-version "0.36.6"',
{
  env: {"ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE":"1"},
  cwd: app.getAppPath()
},
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: When I tried this I got `Error: Cannot find module '/Users/abeall/tools/electron/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Helper.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/init.js'`